# Google Map Custom Marker Dependent on Field Value

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using the code below to populate a Google Map with markers for all the lat and lng values I hold in a MySQL database.

What I would like to do, if at all possible, is to extend this a little more and have the ability to show different coloured markers dependent on a field value, to be more specific, if the value in the field 'finds' is zero then it will be one colour, but if it has a value of one or greater for it to be another colour.

I've found how to do this if the field value is a text value but not numeric. I've tried to change my code, to how (from a beginners perspective) I thought it might be be, but I can't get this to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>All Locations</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 


var customIcons = {       
if 'finds'.value=0: {         
icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',         
shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'       
},       
else {         
icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',         
shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'       
}     
}; 
function load() { 
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
zoom:6, 
mapTypeId: 'roadmap' 
}); 

// Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
downloadUrl("phphfile.php", function(data) { 
var xml = data.responseXML; 
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
var name = markers[i].getAttribute("locationname"); 
var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address"); 
var findsvalue = markers[i].getAttribute("finds"); 
var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lat")), 
parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lon"))); 
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
map: map, 
position: point,
icon: icon.icon, 
shadow: icon.shadow
}); 
} 
}); 
} 

function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
new XMLHttpRequest; 

request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
if (request.readyState == 4) { 
request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
callback(request, request.status); 
} 
}; 

request.open('GET', url, true); 
request.send(null); 
} 

function doNothing() {} 

</script> 

</head> 

<body onLoad="load()"> 
<div id="map"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a lot simpler than I thought.

It was just a case of replacing the text with the numeric value.

Chris